# Dynamically adding a whole row in GridView, or splitting the View

Tags: android, layout, gridview, split, row

I have a GridView with 4 columns, when one is selected, I wanted to dynamically add a whole row underneath the selected cell, and inflate a layout in it, so that I could add some information about the selected cell. Is there anyway to do that? Or maybe, is there a way to split a view in half, then glue it back together when done? Sounds crazy.

Essentially, I'm looking for something you can find on iTunes 11 (see the picture below).

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475721/add-view-between-2-rows-gridview/17584002#17584002

Comment: You could try https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911289/1920735

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You can do that. the xml file where you defined grid view, below that define one linear layout too and make it invisible by adding following code:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

On click the GridView, inflate that layout and set its visibility and use following java codes:

```
LinearLayout l2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);           
View detailView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourInformationLayoutOfGridItem, l2, false);
```

for set visibility true/false by java code:

```
Visibile: l2.setVisibility(0);
Invisible: l2.setVisibility(4);
```

Comment: But wouldn't this inflate a Layout underneath the whole GridView? I need something that would inflate the Layout underneath that specific cell, while pushing the rest of the rows of the GridView downwards.

Comment: Yeah. you are right. I got it. You want it like google Image seach. I am not sure if tableRow can help instead of GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to your question is to simple use TabHost widget:

The XML file to that is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And The java code for that is as below:

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
    }
```

Hope this works fine for you.. And hope this is what you asked for.

Comment: This is for doing a Tab Layout, I'm asking about inflating a Layout in between 2 rows of a GridView. Totally different things.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to add view dynamically... u can use ExpandableListView for that..!!

Comment: I'm saying I want to add a view as a row instead of an item, but while keeping the rest of the GridView as a 'grid' of ImageView for example. Moreover, an ExpandableListView is a whole other thing, you can't even have columns in that.